# Direct3d/C# - Blur area under a rectangle drawn on a sprite

Tags: c#, directx, direct3d, sprite, blur

Any idea how to do it? I am drawing a rectangle that is supposed to be a half-transparent window. I managed to do the transparency by drawing a half-transparent texture, but I also want to blur whatever is under the window.

Normally (eg. using GDI) I would create a bitmap of the area, blur it and paint it as the background of my window. With Direct3D I don't even know how to get the area with whatever is already rendered on it. Or even there can be a different approach, can't it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D3D way is to use a pixel shader to "blur" the area underneath your rect.

[This](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/Series3/Pixel_Shader.php) link shows you how to use a pixel shader in C#.
[And this](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=507209&whichpage=1&#3307485) link has a guassian blur pixel shader.

Answer (score 1):

It DOES require having your backbuffer as a texture.  You can then render the whole thing to a NEW texture and blur the relevant part before putting your semi-trans window over the new texture.

Edit:  AFAIK you can't use the Draw function inside a shader.  You will need to write your own sprite renderer.  The Begin and Draw set up a whole load of states that will break your usage of a vertex shader.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
Surface surf = m_Device.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, BackBufferType.Mono);
How do I get the bitmap or texture from the surface?
Are there any PresentParamenters siginificant for this?
I keep getting an exception on this: Graphics gr = surf.GetGraphics();

Comment: You need to have been rendering to a texture all along.

Comment: Its very easy to set up render-to-texture though :)