# How to implement a Gaussian blur in DirectX?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm rendering a partially transparent rectangle over my game (d3d9) (eventually to be part of a GUI) and I want to blur the contents behind this rectangle. I understand the best way to do with would be with a shader, but that's basically the extent of what I know. Many of the implementations I've found seem far more complex than I should need or they are blurring an image whereas I'm blurring stuff that's already been drawn. A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541961/direct3d-c-blur-area-under-a-rectangle-drawn-on-a-sprite) for C# but received fairly vague answers.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than drawing the objects you want to blur to the screen, draw them to a texture that is bound as the render target. Then, you bind that texture to a compute shader and save the blur result in some other texture. Then you can draw the blurred final result as a "full screen quad", basically a 2d rect that covers the entire screen and will have your scene texture on it. [This article](http://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems/gpugems_ch21.html) is from 2003, so the source code might not be useful, but, it covers the basic idea.